# DIC to compare models with different numbers of parameter?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, hierarchical-bayesian, model-comparison, dic

I am interested in comparing hierarchical Bayesian models based on the same dataset but differing in their spatial and temporal resolution. In short, I am looking at animal population changes over time in a large area. I want to compare models that model population changes between 1 year periods vs. 5 year periods, as well as 1 km2 vs. 10 km2 areas. My model includes categorical spatial and temporal effects (i.e. produce an estimate for each time period and area modelled) and hence, changing either resolution will change the number of parameters the model fits. Can I DIC to compare these models?

Many thanks in advance!